# is it possible to use both ID and class in single list item tag?

Tags: html

is it possible to use both ID and class in single list item tag?

ex

```
<li class="one" ID="two">
```

please suggest some points..

Comment: Yes. Also, this is a HTML question really. Not ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an element can have one ID (which must be unique to the page) and multiple classes at the same time. But when you apply css, the ID has more priority than the class.

**Example:**

```
<li class="one" id="two">hello</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.one
{
color:red;
}
#two
{
color:black;
}
```

The text "**hello**" will appear in black, since id has more priority.

Comment: The text will be black even if you use the class because the further down the style is, the more precedence it gets. Will the ID override the class even if it is above the class?

Comment: hi sir thanks for your suggession but  see my code <li class="widget" id="widgetspace1">     style sheet: #widgetspace1:{margin-top:-38px} that margin-top attribute not reflected in my webpage but if i use <li  class="widget"style="margin-left:-38px"> then it works